# ruby - how can I access an variable

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have this array:

```
{  
:details=>   [  
      {  
     "account"         =>"",
     "address"         =>"",
     "category"         =>"send",
     "amount"         =>0.0,
     "fee"         =>0.0
  },
  {  
     "account"         =>"payment",
     "address"         =>"SXX5kpEyF8w1oK913wVg2ZbJWpLmWnCgAU",
     "category"         =>"receive",
     "amount"         =>1.0
  }
 ]
}
```

How can I access the second "address" element in ruby? When I do

```
address: detail[:address]
```

I get only the first one (which is empty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
data = {  
:details=>   [  
      {  
     "account"         =>"",
     "address"         =>"",
     "category"         =>"send",
     "amount"         =>0.0,
     "fee"         =>0.0
  },
  {  
     "account"         =>"payment",
     "address"         =>"SXX5kpEyF8w1oK913wVg2ZbJWpLmWnCgAU",
     "category"         =>"receive",
     "amount"         =>1.0
  }
 ]
}
```

And then(Because, you never know the sequence of Hashes inside Array):

```
data[:details].detect{|d| !d['address'].empty? }['address']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just address the second element of array

```
obj = {  
:details => [  
  {  
     "account"         =>"",
     "address"         =>"",
     "category"        =>"send",
     "amount"          =>0.0,
     "fee"             =>0.0
  },
  {  
     "account"         =>"payment",
     "address"         =>"SXX5kpEyF8w1oK913wVg2ZbJWpLmWnCgAU",
     "category"        =>"receive",
     "amount"          =>1.0
  }
 ]
}

obj[:details][1]['address']
```

Here is online REPL: http://repl.it/ZZm

Comment: @Anthony what do you mean?

Comment: @Anthony in post author asked for second "address", isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Using the inject method you can get all of them like this:

```
[21] pry(main)> results = []
=> []
[22] pry(main)> json[:details].inject { |sum, k| results << k["address"] }
=> [["SXX5kpEyF8w1oK913wVg2ZbJWpLmWnCgAU"]]
```